# What is じゃねんじゃ.. My friend say it is Tsukkomi but I don't get it

Tags: meaning, usage, contractions

I posted this タイからこんにちは！ in the web somewhere with my Twitter ID. And then there is someone new followed me in Twitter with a tweet タイからこんにちは！ じゃねんじゃ in his timeline. I wonder what that actually means..

This is used by tsukkomi player? How?

Answer (score 2):

It's a dialectal (jocular) expression with a little slack spelling.

> じゃねんじゃ
>   → じゃね**え**んじゃ (restoring contracted vowel)
>   → じゃ**ない**んじゃ (non-vulgar form)
>   → じゃないん**だ（よ）** (Standard Japanese equivalent)

So, it means something like "No way it's that ~", or more tsukkomi-like:

> *"Hello from Thailand"? Oh, come on!*